# GMSMarkers blinking on map when I change the value of tracksViewChanges

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-maps-ios-utils

In my application, I am using `GoogleMaps` and a custom `GMSMarker`. However, my markers are dynamically calculated to decide what they should render or not. For example, when a marker is too close to another, I have a logic for overlap to display or not the title of the marker etc.

My problem started when using many markers, the performance of the app dropped below 40fps. Therefore, I began initializing my markers with the property `tracksViewChanges = false`.

This solved my performance problem, but my markers stopped updating their views. By setting the value of `tracksViewChanges` back to true and then to false again, the markers work almost perfectly, except that every time I change the value, they 'flash' on the screen.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.updatePinOverlap(mapView: mapView)
        }
    }
```

```
func updatePinOverlap(mapView: GMSMapView) {
   for marker in self.discoveryMarker {
           marker.tracksViewChanges = true
           marker.applyOverlapping(pinType: model.pinType ?? .medium,
                                   index: model.zIndex ?? 0)  
           marker.tracksViewChanges = false
        }
    }
```

As mentioned earlier, I tried changing the state of tracksViewChanges, I tried using only UIImage, I tried adding animation to the view, but nothing that really solves my problem.